# error on ggplot2 stat_smooth

Tags: r, ggplot2, gam

I receive an error when I try to use ggplot2 but I do not understand why.
I am probably doing some little mistake somewhere...

```
    > head(d)
      TargetGroup2012 TargetGroup2000     bmi3 age3 PA_Score education3 asthma3 allasthma3 tres3
    1               2               2 20.89796   55        2          2       0          0     0
    2               2               2 20.20038   49        3          2       0          0     0
    3               2               2 30.47797   58        3          1       0          0     0
    4               2               2 34.13111   51        2          2       0          0     0
    5               3               2 23.24380   52        3          1       0          0     0
    6               3               2 16.76574   62        2          3       0          0     0
      wheeze3 SmokingGroup_Kai groupchange
    1       0                4           4
    2       1                4           4
    3       0                5           4
    4       1                4           4
    5       0                3           5
    6       0                3           5
    > 

    ggplot() + 
      stat_smooth(data=d,aes(x=bmi3,y=asthma3),
                  method="gam",
                  formula=asthma3~bmi3, 
                  family="binomial")

# this is the ouput
# Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'asthma3' not found


#this one works

    ggplot()+ stat_smooth(data=d,aes(x=bmi3,y=asthma3),
                  formula=asthma3~bmi3, 
                  family="binomial")
```

What's wrong with my code?

Comment: try to change to `formula = y ~ x` inside `stat_smooth`

Comment: this is working but what if I want a formula with more that one input?

Comment: I gave it a thought, how can you plot multiple regression on a two dimential plot? you should do `facet_grid` by some variable and plot each one of them separatly. Or the best way will be to plot laverage plots

Comment: Yes I want to plot only bmi3 but I want that the estimation of bmi3 takes into account the values of the other predictors.  Something like y=s(x1)+s(x2) and then plot(x1,s(x1))

Comment: You can generate the predictions outside ggplot and then plot them with geom_line.

Comment: yes I know. But ggplot as much more useful option like 'group' and 'color'. If I do not find an answer soon I will be forced to use geom_line but this means much more work to do :-(

Comment: perhaps `facet_wrap` will get you closer to what you're looking for : `ggplot(diamonds,aes(x=carat,y=depth)) + geom_point()+ geom_smooth() + facet_wrap(~clarity)`

Answer (score 4):

Change the formula argument in stat_smooth to:

```
 formula = y ~ x
```